# MySQLSyntaxErrorException MYSTIQUE

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to update my jtable(change value and hit enter) and I get the error. The error is not full due to the size. I think the rest of it is just irrelevant information produced from c3p0 tool for pooling connections.

**Presumptions** At first, I thought it might be the problem of c3p0, cause in order to use it for prepared statements I would have to edit configuration file/change settings. But I used the traditional get connection from DriverManager way to find out it has nothing to do with it.

Another presumption - is some data type problems. Because I type 3.00 and the error says `''Flat' = '3.0' where ID = '4'' at line 1`
Text test line within ImportData method is not executed. So it means it crashes while executing SQL statement. In my database table columns except ID and date are of type float(9,2), meaning total digits = 9; digits "after dot" = 2. And I do have DecimalFormatRenderer class wich might have something to do with this.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Flat' = '3.0' where ID = '4'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
at components.TableWithBottomLine$ImportData.<init>(TableWithBottomLine.java:174)
at components.TableWithBottomLine.tableChanged(TableWithBottomLine.java:147)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(Unknown Source)
at components.TableWithBottomLine$MyTableModel.setValueAt(TableWithBottomLine.java:251)
at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code excerpts from my program:

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int col = e.getColumn();
    model = (MyTableModel) e.getSource();
    String colName = model.getColumnName(col);
    Object cellValue = model.getValueAt(row, col);        
    Object cell_Id = model.getValueAt(row, 0);

    try {
        new ImportData(colName, cellValue, cell_Id);
        bottomLabel.setText(textForLabel());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

public class ImportData {    

    public ImportData(String a, Object b, Object c)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;      

        try {
            connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            String colName = a;             
            String cellValue = b.toString();                
            String cell_Id = c.toString();                      

            String updateString = "update finance.fin " + "set ? = ? " + "where ID = ? "+ ";";
            prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(updateString);
            prepStmt.setString(1, colName);
            prepStmt.setString(2, cellValue);
            prepStmt.setString(3, cell_Id);             
            prepStmt.executeUpdate();  

            System.out.println("Text test line out of ImportData() method");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            closeAll(null, null, prepStmt, connection);
        }  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roel De Nijs from http://coderanch.com
answered the question.
To be honest I see 3 issues with your code. First and most important: I don't think you can do something like this in your prepared statement `"set ? = ? "` I think column names can't be replaced with placeholders. Try using `"set Flat = ? "` and see if it works. If it does, you know what's causing the issues.
The other two are you are setting the parameters as String while they are not strings, but probably a double and an int. So change your code

`prepStmt.setString(1, colName);
prepStmt.setString(2, cellValue);
prepStmt.setString(3, cell_Id);`

to

`// column name not dynamic for test
prepStmt.setDouble(1, cellValue);
prepStmt.setInt(2, cell_Id);`

and see if this works. You should of course make sure that your variables have the appropriate type. PS. Using underscores in variable names is not recommended, according to the naming conventions it should be camelCase. Working code below:

```
public class ImportData {    

    public ImportData(String a, Object b, Object c)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;          
        try {
            connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            String colName = a;             
           // String cellValue = b.toString();
           // String cellId = c.toString();
            float cellValue = (float) b;
            int cellId = (int) c;               
            String updateString = "update finance.fin " + "set " + colName + "= ? " + "where ID = ? "+ ";";
            prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(updateString);
            prepStmt.setFloat(1, cellValue);
            prepStmt.setInt(2, cellId);             
            prepStmt.executeUpdate();  

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            closeAll(null, null, prepStmt, connection);
        }  
    }   
}
```